# angular factory gives Error: [$injector:undef]

Tags: angularjs, factory

Factory looked so simple, but I have no idea what this error is?!?

When my controller calls ReportData.add I get

**Error: [$injector:undef]**

```
app.factory('ReportData', function() {

    var factoryData = [];
    var factoryService = {};

    factoryService.add = function(myData) {
        console.log('FACTORY ADD: ' + myData)
        factoryData = myData;
    };

    factoryService.get = function() {
        console.log('FACTORY GET: ' + factoryData)
        return factoryData;
    };

});

app.controller("test", function ($scope, $http, $location, ReportData) {

    ReportData.add('SENDING DATA TO FACTORY');

    console.log('get it: ' + ReportData.get());

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning the object at the end of the function, this is why angular is unable to inject the factory.

When you inject the factory angular look for all the registered factories, then executes the corresponding function (only once) and cache the returning object that is the same object that angular will inject inside your controller.

If you don't return anything inside the function angular is not able to resolve your dependency.

```
app.factory('ReportData', function() {

  var factoryData = [];
  var factoryService = {};

  factoryService.add = function(myData) {
    console.log('FACTORY ADD: ' + myData)
    factoryData = myData;
  };

  factoryService.get = function() {
    console.log('FACTORY GET: ' + factoryData)
    return factoryData;
  };
  return factoryService; //you're missing this return statement
});
```

Comment: woah!!  that did something... now my factory went into infinite loop. I guess putting everything in the app.js was a bad idea :-D

Comment: Auch... how to I make it stop?  I even killed the webserver, and it still keeps spitting out these:  [link](https://db.tt/bQ5a36cICW)

Comment: there should be some other error in your code . this code looks fine with the return statement

Comment: Got it!! haha one of those examples where having a super fast PC works against you. It was spamming errors so fast that I couldnt empty the cache.  Anyway, I solved it and it works GREAT now!!!  Thank you so much @Karim :-)

Comment: glad you fixed it :)